# Feed list of URL´s from a Button to WebView XCODE 4.5

Tags: ios, xcode, url, webview

Good morning.

I´m trying to develop a small app, and I need some help...

I need to pass a URL from a button to a WebView. I have 4 buttons, when I choose BT1 it will open a WebView with url=www.google.com, when i choose BT2 it will open the same webview but with a different url (www.apple.com).

Thank´s for your help.

Answer (score 1):

don't forget to assign the actions to the buttons & implementing UIWebViewDelegate in your ViewController...

```
-(IBAction)button1Clicked:(id)sender{
    [self loadWebViewWithURL:@"http://www.google.com"];
    }

    -(IBAction)button2Clicked:(id)sender{
    [self loadWebViewWithURL:@"http://www.apple.com"];
    }

    -(IBAction)button3Clicked:(id)sender{
    [self loadWebViewWithURL:@"http://www.yahoo.com"];
    }

    -(IBAction)button4Clicked:(id)sender{
    [self loadWebViewWithURL:@"http://www.microsoft.com"];
    }

    -(void)loadWebViewWithURL:(NSString*)urlstr{

        NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlstr] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0f];
        [myWebView loadRequest:request];
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help, but could you please guide me a little bit more? I created a new project, new Simple View Application and I create the four buttons and put your code in the ViewController.m file and got a few erros:

Comment: how much more? did you try this code? if you are very new to IOS programming then you need to learn IOS by millions of tutorials available online. if you have specific issues then you are welcome to ask

Comment: can I send you a print screen?

Comment: you could post your print screen in this question by using image feature

Comment: you are missing : between loadWebViewWithURL and string URL.. check my code properly what I wrote, secondly you have not defined any UIWebView, it is not UIViewController for loading reaquest

Comment: you need to learn how to program in IOS, this is not the way you are doing, this myWebViewController is useless, you need to delete it and add UIWebView as IBOutlet to your ViewController.xib and implement the Delegate UIWebViewDelegate in ViewController

Comment: Yes, I need to learn mutch more, but please verify this two print screens.

Comment: In your .h file after definition of ViewController add the delegate like this <UiWebViewDelegate>

Comment: Hi. Did you see my last printscreen? Why do I get that error? It seems all done as you said.

Comment: you need to synthesize your myWebView in .m class and then use your [myWebView loadRequest];

Comment: Sorry if i´m asking to mutch, but what if I want the Buttons in ViewController1 and the UIWebView in another ViewController?

Comment: Hi. Now I have a ViewController1 with 2 buttons. And a second ViewController2 whith a UIWebView.

What I´m trying to do:

1- when i click Button1 in ViewController1 it goes to UIWebView in ViewController(2) and open @"www.google.com".

2 - When I click Button2 in ViewController1 it goes to the same UIWebView in ViewController2 and open @"www.apple.com".

thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi gulliver007, could you please guide me doing this?